# WSO2 | Class Invoking admin services on worker node is forbidden

Tags: wso2

I have a distributed wso2 deployment. While publishing an API, I get an error. Why does the error come?

- log of gateway:

> Class Invoking admin services on worker node is forbidden...

- log of publisher:

  ```
  APIGatewayManager Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox
  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while obtaining API information from gateway. The input stream for an incoming message is null.
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.getApi(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:149)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIGatewayManager.publishToGateway(APIGatewayManager.java:102)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.publishToGateway(APIProviderImpl.java:1519)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(APIProviderImpl.java:1328)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.propergateAPIStatusChangeToGateways(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:36)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.executors.APIExecutor.execute(APIExecutor.java:136)
      at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.runCustomExecutorsCode(DefaultLifeCycle.java:712)
      at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.extensions.aspects.DefaultLifeCycle.invoke(DefaultLifeCycle.java:450)
      at org.wso2.carbon.governance.registry.eventing.handlers.GovernanceEventingHandler.invokeAspect(GovernanceEventingHandler.java:338)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.invokeAspect(HandlerManager.java:2792)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.invokeAspect(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:518)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.invokeAspect(EmbeddedRegistry.java:2591)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.invokeAspect(CacheBackedRegistry.java:510)
      at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.invokeAspect(UserRegistry.java:1952)
      at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:829)
      at org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.common.dataobjects.GovernanceArtifactImpl.invokeAction(GovernanceArtifactImpl.java:808)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.changeLifeCycleStatus(APIProviderImpl.java:3755)
      at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.changeLifeCycleStatus(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:148)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c5._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag:13)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c5.call(/publisher/modules/api/life-cycles.jag)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_13(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:47)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:64)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag:5)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
      at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
      at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.life_cycles.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/life-cycles/ajax/life-cycles.jag)
      at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
      at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
      at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
      at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
      at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
      at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
      at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
      at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
      at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
      at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
      at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
      at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't invoke Admin services through a worker node. If you want to access Admin services you need to call them via management node.

Comment: thanks. I had started the gateway with worker profile instead of gateway manager.

Comment: How can this be answered in a non-manager GW environment (GW-Manager is deprecated as of 2.6)?